Debugging Rust-pyo3 lifetime errors
I am trying to convert a custom rust type into a Bound<PyAny>, however I keep running into rust lifetime errors which I can't seem to resolve even with explicit lifetime identifiers.
My function is as follows:
pub fn do_something<'a>(
    specs: &Bound<PyAny>,
    numbs: Vec<f64>,
) -> PyResult<Bound<'a, PyAny>> {
    ...
      // do something with specs and numbs
      // get spec
    ...

    Python::with_gil(|py : Python<'a>|{
        let s = match spec {
            Operator::variant1(x) => {
                let pyref: Py<Variant1Wrapper> =
                    Py::new(py, Variant1Wrapper { internal: x }).unwrap();
                pyref.to_object(py).into_bound(py)
            }
            Operator::variant2(x) => {
                let pyref: Py<Variant2Wrapper> =
                    Py::new(py, Variant2Wrapper { internal: x }).unwrap();
                pyref.to_object(py).into_bound(py)
            }
        };

        Ok(s)

    })



The rust-analyser gives the following error at pyref.to_object(py).into_bound(py) :
lifetime may not live long enough
returning this value requires that '1 must outlive '2
do_something.rs(170, 33): has type `pyo3::Python<'1>`
do_something.rs(170, 40): return type of closure is pyo3::Bound<'2, pyo3::PyAny>

UPDATE: @kmdreko's answer solves the initial issue.
Additionally, how would one proceed if none of the function arguments are of type Bound<T> i.e.
pub fn do_something<'a>(
    numbs: Vec<f64>,
) -> PyResult<Bound<'a, PyAny>> 


If you already have a Bound (e.g. specs), then you already have the GIL. You can get it via .py(). That way you avoid the shortened 'a within Python::with_gil. And then specs needs the lifetime annotated as &Bound<'a, PyAny> so the flow matches.

Lifetimes in Rust help annotate how long a reference (or reference wrapper) is valid. So, when considering lifetimes in the return position, nothing within the function body can supply a lifetime valid for outside the function, so the lifetime must be bound to something passed into the function ('statics are an exception but they aren't relevant here). So on its face, your function signature should bind 'a to a paramter (in this case specs: &Bound<'a, PyAny>).
Specifically with pyo3, they commonly use lifetimes to indicate that the GIL (global interpretter lock) is held so that you can safely access data from Python. That means that simply the existence of a Bound means the GIL is held and you can retrieve a non-bound token for it via .py(). And thus with that Py you can return anything using that original lifetime parameter.
pub fn do_something<'a>(
    specs: &Bound<'a, PyAny>, // <---------
    numbs: Vec<f64>,
) -> PyResult<Bound<'a, PyAny>> {
    // do something with specs and numbs get spec
    let spec = ...;

    let py = specs.py(); // <--------------
    let s = match spec {
        Operator::variant1(x) => {
            let pyref: Py<Variant1Wrapper> =
                Py::new(py, Variant1Wrapper { internal: x }).unwrap();
            pyref.to_object(py).into_bound(py)
        }
        Operator::variant2(x) => {
            let pyref: Py<Variant2Wrapper> =
                Py::new(py, Variant2Wrapper { internal: x }).unwrap();
            pyref.to_object(py).into_bound(py)
        }
    };

    Ok(s)
}

The reason Python::with_gil doesn't help you here is because the py parameter only lives for the scope of the closure (even if the GIL is already held). So nothing derived from it can satisfy the outer 'a lifetime. Your attempt to annotate the lifetime explicitly there is rejected by the compiler because you can't dictate what is provided to the closure.

Thanks for your the detailed answer. What can one do if there isn't an argument with Bound to derive py in the function?

@Maybeagreyhound Then you cannot return a Bound from this function. You will either have to take a Python or return a Py.

@Maybeagreyhound The PyO3 user guide has some guidance for accepting a py: Python<'_> parameter.
